# Why aren't my emails sending from CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mandrill

My codeigniter script will not send emails.  I have tested sendmail on xampp with a native PHP email script and it works.  This is definitely a problem with CI or my config.  The send() function always returns false and the print_debugger() function is always blank.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php

            $config = array(
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_user' => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => '#############',
                'smtp_port' => '465'
            );

            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->from($this->stg['site_name']);
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email_address'));
            $this->email->subject('Your Account Email Has Been Changed');

            $data = array(
                'activation_code' => $this->member->activation_code
            );

            $message = $this->load->view('emailTemplates/change_email', $data, true);

            $this->email->message($message);

            if(!$this->email->send()){

                $this->template->overallHeader('Email Failed');

                $data = array(
                    'title' => 'Email Sending Failed',
                    'message' => 'The system failed to dispatch the email message to your new email address.  Because of this, the email address on your account has NOT been changed. '.$this->email->print_debugger()
                );

                $this->load->view('errorBody', $data);              

            } else {

                //do stuff

            }
```

I have also tried static strings instead of the form input variables as the to and from, etc.

Comment: Obvious first question, do you have a mail server running

Comment: I have set up Mercury with Xampp.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sending via Mandrill SMTP wouldn't require a local mail server to be running. It's a third-party sending service.

Comment: I suggest that you temporarily add some debugging statements (var_dump(), etc.) in the _send_with_smtp() function in CodeIgniter's CI_Email class...hopefully that will help you determine the issue.

Comment: So I've gotten sendmail to work from xampp by using gmail smtp... but it only works in native php and never in codeigniter.